# Is it possible to export env variable via Upstart?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, upstart

I need to export a variable `FOO=stringhere` so that system processes could use it. And the place I would like to do this, is Upstart job.

Unfortunately, I tried as per Upstart manual to do `env FOO=stringhere` http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#environment-variables

But after the system is booted, `echo $FOO` returns nothing.

Am I trying to do something impossible, or are there any gotchas I should know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the page you refer to says,

> Upstart allows you to set environment variables **which will be accessible to the jobs whose job configuration files they are defined in**.

The indicates that the variables are set in the environment used *by the system daemons* at startup. The *user* environment is configured separately once you log in.

If you want to check whether the daemon knows about the variable you set, you can test that by *temporarily* modifying its startup script and adding something like `logger "=============== The variable FOO is set to $FOO ====================="`. You should then see the information logged during boot-up (look in `/var/log/messages` for example).

Comment: Any ideas on how I could work around this feature?

Comment: What do you mean by *feature* here? What is your goal - knowing if the variable is used at system startup (see my edit for that) or having the variable exported to all your users' shell sessions?

Comment: Yes, so that every user on the system could type `echo $FOO` and get the `stringhere`.

Comment: You answered "yes" to which one of the two @rozcietrzewiacz's question?

Comment: Well, you could force the startup script append a specific variable to the system profile file, but are you sure it is what you want? Don't you just need to have the variable visible to all users (but *not* necessarily being exported by a specific startup job)?

Comment: Yes, I need a public variable. Can you make it any other way (programmatically during bootup)?

Comment: If you really just want to have a "public" variable visible to all users, then a system startup job is **not** the place to set it. But your question points at a problem of setting a variable which, as you wrote, *system processes could use*. This is a different issue (also useful). So please decide to either modify the question or ask a separate one.

Answer (score 3):

In your example that variable could be used in the same file.

Note from upstart cookbook.

> Note that a Job Configuration File does not have access to a user's environment variables, not even the superuser. This is not possible since all job processes created are children of init which does not have a user's environment.

Further explanation from upstart cookbook.

Lets say you write `env TESTING=123` in your *.conf file, then you can use this variable in your script block below (the one you used)

```
script
  # prints "TESTING='123'" to system log
  logger -t $0 "TESTING='$TESTING'"
end script
```

Or a bit more sophisticated approach would let you use you variable in jobs that 'listen' to your job:

```
# /etc/init/A.conf
start on wibble
export foo

# /etc/init/B.conf
start on A
script
  logger "value of foo is '$foo'"
end script
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to accomplish is better suited to `/etc/profile` which is `source`'ed by login shells.

`export foo="String here"`