# How can I make a public variable in Linux that all users would see?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I need to have a variable `$FOO` on the system that contains a string all users could use, but I have no idea how to create one.

The Upstart job is obviously not a solution as from this thread - [Is it possible to export env variable via Upstart?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20780/is-it-possible-to-export-env-variable-via-upstart)

But I have no idea where else I should look, being Windows developer for a very long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to the answers already given, other places to set the variable would be:

- a file under `/etc/env.d` (shell-independent),
- `/etc/bash/bashrc` for bash users,
- `/etc/zshenv` or `/etc/zprofile` or `/etc/zshrc` or `/etc/zlogin` for zsh (as per `man zsh`),
- other shell-specific config files, described in each shell's manpage under `FILES` section.

Comment: They all are manual entries, but I somehow need to change it per reboot programmatically... :( Should I add a variable in `FOO=``expression to eval```

Comment: Yes, you can use something like `FOO="$(some command)"`. But maybe you could just describe what you need exactly - there may be a method that you overlooked and all the struggle with variables is unnecessary (or can be simplified).

Comment: There is a shell script that has a variable with a location to network machine. But upon bootup I need to change the IP in that script, because IP of target machine can change. I can query it via script though, but it would be great if I could do that just once, while booting.

Comment: OK! This is something that doesn't need any environmental variable being set, just an entry in `/etc/hosts` which you might modify at startup.

Answer (score 4):

Many distributions use `/etc/environment` for this purpose. There is some information about it on the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables) and the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_Variables), among others.

Answer (score 4):

If `/etc/environment` doesn't exist, then you could use either`/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d/FOO` to set up your environment.